# SSL on synology behind router

Tags: router, nas, ssl

I am trying to enable ssl on my synology. The problem is, synology is behind the router and can access publicly using port forward.

Let say my public ip is 94.94.94.94

I access my synology publicly using https://94.94.94.94:5001
This works OK but there is always "not secured" warning on browser.

When I tried to add new certificate from lets encrypt on synology security tab, it return an error because i think lets encrypt is looking at the synology on port 80 but that is not the correct port. That is for the router web administration.

I was able to install Let'sEncrypt on one of synology NAS I had before but that is to the expense of losing access to web administration of the router.

Any suggestion on how to ssl a synology so that it does not show "not secured" error on browsers?

Comment: A certificate to a IP?  These should not be issued by LE, IMO.  You need to use other certbot challenges (and possibly manual one).  BTW I doesn't recommend your method. Doesn't make 5001 accessible from outside. Use router or synology VPN, and then connect to 5001.

Comment: we want to make the server accessible from outside to share files from synology DSM file manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a let's encrypt certificate to an IP adress, especially since most ISPs are  giving out temporary IPs to its customers. That means, your IP adress is subject to change every few days, or at least on every reconnect. You need to get a domain name to assign the certificate to, at least a free one.

Furthermore, you need to forward port 80 and 443 to your NAS for let's encrypt-verification. It certainly won't look up port 5001 to verify that the system the certificate is requested from really belongs to that domain name. At least for the verification process (which repeats itself each time the certificate is renewed) these ports need to be forwarded.

And, as alreay mentioned in the comments, it is not advisable to forward port 5001 to your synology, since this is the web admin interface, and gives complete access to your system if someone has the right credentials or a security vulerability. So use VPN or only expose unprivileged services to the global internet. There is a point in having a firewall in your router.

Of course, you can always use a self-signed certificate, although this won't give you the same degree of security. But you can trust the self-signed certificate in your browser once, and you'll be notified if the certificate changes because e.g. someone is eavesdropping on you.

Comment: We have static IP from ISP that we are paying. The reason we need to overcome the browser warning is because we are sharing files to our clients using synology file manager. Every time we share a link they get the nasty error. Some know how to bypass it but most of them just comes back to us saying the link is not working.